# Is it possible to generate 2 different login authenticators django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am fairly new to django and I am trying to develop a web based game.

I want the game to have 2 seperate log ins, one for a user log in and one for a character 'selection', obviously I can't go to the character selection without requiring the login_required decorator, but at the same time I want to make the rest of my website based upon the "character" and therefore I essentially need another login(character)_required, I was wondering if there is simpler way to do this rather than trying to rewrite djangos login functionality.

I would appreciate it if I could be pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Read his article https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my issue